# Looping PivotTable through Worksheets - FAILS when AddDataField

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have processed multiple modules to the overall script I am working on and this is the only component that is not working well for me. I can get the initial setup of the PivotTable to work, but when added a Sum field it goes awry. Any feedback on the below would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Sub PivotChart2()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "ZIP_US" Then
        'Do Noathing
    Else

        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set PDATA = Range("$A$1:$F" & LastRow)
        Dim PVTNAME As String
        Dim PT As PivotTable

        PVTNAME = Range("$K$1")

        Sheets(ws.Name).Select


        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        PDATA, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        ws.Name & "!R3C10", TableName:=Range("$K$1"), DefaultVersion:=6



        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("STATE")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
        .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("SALES"), "Sum of SALES", xlSum
        End With

    End If

Next ws




        'pvt.PivotFields("STATE").Orientation = xlRowField
        'pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("SALES"), "Sum of SALES", xlSum

End Sub
```

The part of code the gives me an error is as follows:

```
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
        .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("SALES"), "Sum of SALES", xlSum
        End With
```

Error as follows: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Comment: Define "awry". What is the error you get and on what line? Is it consistent?

Comment: Peter - Thank you for taking a look. I have added the error line and the Error code that I receive when running the macro.

Comment: That error usually means the field ("SALES" in this case) is not included as part of the pivot table. Try performing what you want manually and capturing it as a recorded macro and see how it compares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter - As you stated I needed to process this as a manual sequence and review the code. I just did that and found that the line in question needed to be adapted to be:

```
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        1).PivotFields("SALES"), "Sum of SALES", xlSum
```

Comment: Please note that I built my code in Excel 2016 and when processing in 2010 it does not work. So I will review and see what I can do to make that work